# What are the SEO implications of switching from a longer 10 year old ".com" domain name to a shorter ".supply"?

Tags: seo, multiple-domains

We are reorganising our company's focus and product line from working with only sport products to a much wider range of footwear, clothing and bags. Our old domain name is `winksport.com` and I want to switch it to `wink.supply`, what are the SEO and other implications of this? Is it worth doing?

Comment: You would loose all of your old domains trust rank and will be starting over. A major component of trust rank is domain age. This would be gone as well as all of your back links. You can 301 redirect your old domain to the new to preserve much of this, however, as it always turns out, this becomes temporary as the decision eventually comes to delete the old domain. In that, you will need to rebuild your link profile all over again. This question has been answered here many times.

Comment: "longer" / "shorter" - Size would appear to be irrelevant... if you include the TLD (which is longer) there's only 2 chars difference. (?)

Comment: To all the posters who think "lose" is spelled "loose", how do you spell loose?

Answer (score 2):

As per my practical implementation for the same, I found it's only matters when there is good amount of quality backlinks for the current domain. Otherwise only the age factor does not matter for SEO.

Answer (score 1):

At 10 years, I am sure your domain has a good rank and a number of incoming links. Gosh, you are likely to lose all of that juice, and which isn't an easy way to go for your new domain. However, you can use a Redirection from your old site to the new site for to make use of the already established juice. Just make sure that you use the same CMS and keep all permalinks the same.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say **no, don't do it**:

- **The shorter url isn't worth a lot**. We're talking about a absolute minimum abount of value. Rephrazing one sentence is worth more.
- **You have collected an amount of backlinks**. Backlinks have to be redirected, losing a bit of SEO value in the process, and the anchor itself loses some juice
- **You give up an domain that exists for quite some time**. An old domain has value as it is some indication about the reliability (based on "if it's  crap, it wont last long").
- The `.supply` domain isn't that common, it might confuse people
- All the people who remember your url now remember an old url

What you can do is the other way arround, make the `.supply` be an alias for de `.com`, a little geeky extra feature.

Comment: I know what "losing" is but what is "loosing"?

Comment: @Rob: Thanks for correcting a non-native english speaker in a respectful way

Answer (score 0):

If your only reason for switching is a shorter URL, I would highly recommend you stick with the old domain name.

While you will regain some of the juice with the redirects it will most likely only be a portion of it and it will not happen over night.

Plus, your domain name is very short anyway!